# Why is this method not recognising the existence of my array in C#?

Tags: c#, arrays, for-loop, data-structures

I am trying to complete some coursework, our exercise is focused around using data structures. I am trying to write a new method to print out each element in the array I have created but my for loop is not recognising the existence of the array that has been created above it. It is giving me an error at the 'students.Length' part.

I'm sorry if this is a really stupid question because I feel like there's a very simple answer to this but I just can't understand why it's telling me the 'students' array doesn't exist?

```
public struct student_data
{
    public string forename;
    public string surname;
    public int id_number;
    public float averageGrade;

}

static void populateStruct(out student_data student, string fname, string surname, int id_number)
{
    student.forename = fname;
    student.surname = surname;
    student.id_number = id_number;
    student.averageGrade = 0.0F;

}

public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    student_data[] students = new student_data[4];
    populateStruct(out students[0], "Mark", "Anderson", 1);
    populateStruct(out students[1], "Max", "Fisher", 2);
    populateStruct(out students[2], "Tom", "Jones", 3);
    populateStruct(out students[3], "Ewan", "Evans", 4);
}

static void printAllStudent(student_data student)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < students.Length; i++)
  
}
```

Comment: I'd suggest not using `out`.  Instead have your method return the `student_data` and assign it to the array.

Comment: You need to declare that student_data[] outside your Main method. It's now just a local variable

Comment: The array you're passing in is called student not students.

Comment: @FrederikTobner It's also not an array.

Comment: Is student_data[] students = new student_data[4] not creating an array called 'students'? The assignment requires us to use out so i can't change that part... I'm gonna fail this module.

Comment: Side note: please talk to your teacher to understand why you are using `struct` - since it is somewhat advanced concept in C# (especially for people with JavaScript/Python background) I'm surprised that you are using it before understanding arrays/method calls.

Comment: `student_data[] students = new student_data[4]` *is* creating a new array, but it is local to the Main method and not known outside it. You can *declare* `student_data[] students` at class level (outside the method) and then initialize it (`students = new student_data[4]`) inside your Main

Comment: You never call `printAllStudent`. If you call it from Main (and fix parameters), `students` may remain local

Answer (score 1):

In `printAllStudent`, you are trying to retrieve the length of a variable named `students`. This is not the same variable you have received, which is named `student`. As a result, `students` is undefined in the body of `printAllStudent`.

Comment: It's not just the name.  The signature needs to include `[]` as well.

Answer (score 0):

The `printAllStudent` method is currently taking in a single `student_data` struct as an argument rather than a `student_data[]` array. Additionally, you're trying to access the `students` array that was defined inside another method, which is not accessible. Instead, you should use the array that's passed into the method:

```
static void printAllStudent(student_data[] input)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < input.Length; i++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(input[i]);
    }
}
```

Also, to make the output more useful, it might be a good idea to override the `ToString` method on your `student_data` struct so that it outputs some information about the student. For example:

```
public struct student_data
{
    public string forename;
    public string surname;
    public int id_number;
    public float averageGrade;

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return $"{id_number}: {forename} {surname} (avg grade: {averageGrade})";
    }
}
```